# Exceeded or exceeding

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses, causatives, causative-have

This is a sentence extracted from a book named “Into thin air”:

> I’d written more than sixty pieces for Outside over the previous fifteen tears, and seldom **had** the travel budget for any of these assignments **exceeded** two or three thousand dollars.

I don’t know why it is **exceeded** but not **exceeding**. According to [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exceed?q=Exceed) **exceed something** means
to be greater than a particular number or amount and this is the example offered:

> The price will not exceed £100

Therefore, in the sentence above, I would expect it is:

> [...] seldom had the travel budget for any of these assignments which exceeded two or three thousand dollars.

When a reduced relative clause is used, it should be

> [...] assignments exceeding two or three thousand dollars.

I wonder whether that is the causative form “have something done” in the origin sentence but I still can’t make out why they use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a relative clause, it's just a normal phrase in the past perfect tense. It's just the word order that's confusing; a more simple ordering would be:

> The budget for these assignments had seldom exceeded two or three thousand dollars.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't "exceeding" because this whole line is in the past-perfect tense (sometimes called the "pluperfect"). The word order is a bit confusing, but we could untangle it and remove some unnecessary clauses to come up with

> Over the previous fifteen years, the travel budget had seldom exceeded two or three thousand dollars.

The author sets a reference time by saying "over the previous 15 years" -- we read that as having a reference time at the end of the period -- and then the travel budgets for each of those works took place during that 15 year period, prior to the reference time, or in the past from a reference point in the past, so the past-perfect is required.

In the past-perfect tense, you use 'had' plus the past-tense verb.

The only way you could use a present-tense verb in that phrase is if it related to some action happening at that before-the-past point: "I **had seen** the criminal **running** away from the house."

In that case, we have the past-perfect in "had seen", and then actions happening concurrently to that act of seeing become present-tense.